# Unable to create a Virtual Directory from VS2010 with a name other than localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

I am getting Exception

"Unable to create virtual directory.Could not find the server 'https:devlocal.com/test' on local machine. Make sure the local IIS server has been configured to support secure communication."

1.I had added a host entry for 127.0.0.1 devlocal.com

now when i am trying to create virtual directory from VS2010 it is displaying above mentioned exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had removed the default binding to port 80 (which I assume Visual Studio uses to request IIS creates a virtual directory).

Adding this back in solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In command window navigate to "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727"

```
                            - then run "ASPNET_REGIIS -i"

                            - then run "ASPNET_REGIIS -ga ASPNET"
```

- Within IIS Manager add "Integrated Windows authentication" to Authentication methods for "Default Web Site"

**Note:** Assumption that your boot drive is C

Comment: hi Chris,Can you please let me know in what way this helps me

Comment: Hi Chris, 

 Issue is not fixed.run "ASPNET_REGIIS -i" does not solve my problem.

My Issue is I had changed '127.0.0.1 devlocal.com' in my host file.I am able to create virtual directory from vs2010 if my url is 
'Https://localhost/test'.But i am not able to create the virtual using 'Https://devlocal.com/test'.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Host Header resolved the issue for my case. Hope you got some resolution - if so, please update us as well.

[image: Host Header value in IIS]

As depicted above, specifying the Host Header Value as well as adding Network Service with Full access rights for the actual physical folder of the site has resolved the issue.

Hope this helps someone, as I didn't got any clear details from any source. Please note that I'm using Windows 2K3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll often get this if you either change the default port binding as per another answer or if you're using host header files and you alter the IP address to something specific like `192.168.1.1` instead of using `All Unassigned`.

I believe Visual Studio uses `127.0.0.1:80` to talk to IIS for this properties dialog. So if your site in IIS uses bindings other than that such as

```
127.0.0.1:67
```

or

```
192.168.1.1:80
```

it will fail.